# UITabBarItem loses tint in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My application has a `UINavigationController` embedded within a `UITabBarController`. I have everything setup and it works properly with each tab bar item having a blue tint when selected. In one case where I push to a new view and then go back the tint of the tab bar item is grayed out.

Why is the tab bar losing its tint on the selected button after returning to the view from a pushed `viewController`?

Comment: It could be some settings on your storyboard or code on your view controller. Without a sample project on Github, it is hard to pinpoint where exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you debug until you post some code, but to correctly do this, you would put the following code in your `viewDidLoad` method of your `TabBarController.m` file:

```
[[self tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Maybe if you're choosing the tint on the storyboard, do it like this and it will work.